# Adobe Flash AIR override Android back button

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

In my AIR AS3 app I'm trying to override Back Button like this:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKey );

private function onKey(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK)
    {
        //stage.addChild(new MainMenuScreen());
        //stage.removeChild(this);
        //removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKey);
    }
}
```

It seems to me that my code is getting done but the default Android behaviour *(App is closed)* is executed as well.
Have someone faced this problem?

Comment: Don't change default behaviour.

Comment: May this link can help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549669/air-as3-stage-keylistener-overriding-input-textfield/15556087#15556087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys for your help!
The problem was due to my FlashDevelop IDE. I used PackageApp.bat instead of Run.bat, so wrong versions of my .apk were deployed onto device. Hope this post will help others who may face this problem

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop the app closing, you should intercept the EXITING event:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, exitHandler);

function exitHandler(event:Event):void
{
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I guess i should add that you can manually close the app with:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent the default action *(closing the application)* but make sure you still allow the application to close if there's nothing else to do *(by using a `readyToClose` variable, for example)*:

```
private function onKey(e:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK)
    {
        if(!readyToClose)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            //stage.addChild(new MainMenuScreen());
            //stage.removeChild(this);
            //removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: by some unknown reason e.preventDefault(); does not work at all as if I didn't wrote it

Comment: did you try it without the `if(!readyToClose)` part etc to see if it works at all?

Comment: Thank you. I already found solution. It wasn't due to code, rather to IDE. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it - if you use multiple stages you can put this in frame 1 of your first action panel

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, CheckKeypress, false, 0, true)

function CheckKeypress(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    switch (event.keyCode) 
    { 
        case Keyboard.BACK: 
        event.preventDefault();
        gotoAndPlay (1);
        break; 
        case Keyboard.MENU: 
        trace("Menu key is pressed.");
        break; 
        case Keyboard.SEARCH: 
        trace("Search key is pressed."); 
        break; 
        } 
        }
```